# How do you do NAT port redirection with PF?

Tags: iptables, firewall, pf

In Linux, you can do NAT port redirection with a command like this:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8000
```

What is the equivalent with BSD's [PF](http://www.openbsd.org/faq/pf/rdr.html)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this with `Packet Filter` :

> pass in on em0 proto tcp from any to any port 80 rdr-to 192.168.1.20 port 8000

Change `em0` with your network interface, and change the IP address to suit your needs.

Read more : http://www.openbsd.org/faq/pf/rdr.html#filter